# Using certbot with 18.04 - issues with "add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot"

Tags: apt, ppa

Unable to get this command to work:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~certbot/ubuntu/certbot'.
ERROR: '~certbot' user or team does not exist.
~$
```

Have searched in vain but none of the solutions seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

> nano /etc/resolv.conf

## add blow 2 lines if not present already.

> nameserver 8.8.8.8
>
> nameserver 8.8.4.4

Answer (score 0):

Are you working behind a VPN or a Firewall? You might want to check your outbound connection, with a particular look at the conf file.

Alternatively, you might want to consider verifying that the repositories are enabled:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Good luck

Comment: I am working behind a hardware firewall device that works fine for all other apt-get queries

Comment: As the problem is not about finding a particular package, enabling or disabling official repositories won't help.

Comment: apt-add-repository is part of the package software-properties-common not apt.  Can you post ` software-properties-gtk -d`

Comment: # software-properties-gtk -d
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Please don't tell me you do it as root? As normaler user again and edit your Question for output.

Answer (score 0):

reinstall the CA certificates:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
```

https://itsfoss.com/fix-add-ppa-error-ubuntu-1404-linux-mint/